# Get value from a dom tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do need help to get a tag value, i've tried several methods but they doens't work, sorry i'm quite new.

I have a code like this:

```
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="1111">
</a>
</div>
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="2222">
</a>
</div>
```

I have many divs like that with different data-dfid.

What I need it's to go trough all the data-dfid ocurrenciesinto the dom and get the value into a var.

I'm trying with document.getattribute but it doens't work:

```
for (i=0;i<whatever;i++) {
var datadfid = document.getAttribute('data-dfid').value;
{
```

I need that datafid var get the value of the data-dfid so first ocurrence soulg be datafid = 1111 second datafid = 2222
I've tried several methods but they doesn't work, i'm quite new with this. Also I have no ID into that tag so not able to use getelementsbyID

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, ID would be bad idea anyway as you would have to consciously make them unique in the output.

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all of the matching elements and a foreach to loop through them and `getAttribute` to get the string in data-dfid.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".df-card-main");

links.forEach(function(e){
  console.log(e.getAttribute("data-dfid"));
});
```

```html
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="1111">
</a>
</div>
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="2222">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will fulfill your requirements

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".df-card-main")

for(const card of cards){
    console.log(card.getAttribute("data-dfid"))
}
```

```html
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="1111">
</a>
</div>
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="2222">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare variable inside for each, last one will always overwrite the previous one as the loop will progress to its end.

You can **NOT** have  `datafid = 1111` and `datafid = 2222` IN SAME TIME.

**datafid** is name of the variable and you can not have it twice.

You can declare a array and push each value into it. Later you can do what you want with that array.

Also there is no value in a elements. It is used just for `inputs` etc. just use `.getAttribute('data-dfid')`

```js
var datadfid = [];

[...document.querySelectorAll('.df-card-main')].forEach(el => { 
datadfid.push(el.getAttribute('data-dfid')); 
  })

console.log(datadfid);
```

```html
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="1111">
</a>
</div>
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="2222">
</a>
</div>
```

Or use `datadfid +=el.getAttribute('data-dfid')`  `+=` that will push every new data attribute at end of variable.

```js
var datadfid = "";

[...document.querySelectorAll('.df-card-main')].forEach(el => { 
datadfid += el.getAttribute('data-dfid'); 
  })

console.log(datadfid);
```

```html
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="1111">
</a>
</div>
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="2222">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataset` property on top the element through which you can access the custom attribute `data-dfid` like `elem.dataset.dfid`. For more info on `data-*` attributes and the usage [refer here](https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties#non-standard-attributes-dataset)

```js
const dfidValues = [];

const cardMains = document.querySelectorAll(".df-card-main");

cardMains.forEach(cardMain => {
  //For each iteration the value will be corresponding to that particular element with `data-dfid` attribute
  //i.e., first it'll be 1111, then 2222
  console.log(cardMain.dataset.dfid);

  //If you want to store the values for later use, you can do the following
  dfidValues.push(cardMain.dataset.dfid);
})

//Use dfidValues here once after fetching all the values from dom
console.log(dfidValues);
```

```html
<div class="df-card">
  <a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="1111">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="df-card">
  <a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="2222">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[each loop](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery.

```js
$( ".df-card-main" ).each(function() {
 var dfif_val = $(this).attr( "data-dfid" );
 console.log(dfif_val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="1111">
</a>
</div>
<div class="df-card">
<a class="df-card-main" data-dfid="2222">
</a>
</div>
```